# getting input values from form in td from table

Tags: javascript, html

I have all these funnctions which need to perform when a user inputs values into a text box that take only numbers. I also want to display a message in the target text box when the value is not a number, soliciting them to insert a valid value. When the input data is correct I want the function to do a calculation on those values and display them in a target td. Also when no values are inserted I want the td to display 0€. I have tried using the inner.HTML method.

I know I need to trigger an event to the functions, but am not sure which would be the best way to do it.

I also have doubts if I can write the HTML markup as I did, inserting an input tag inside a td tag.

Given that the markup is legal, I need help in writing just the first function and getting it to work. All other functions are commented out.

Here is the link to Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/mqu7A/

```
   var A = {

       //calculate the total invoiced for the day
       calcTotalDay: function () {
           //get the total invoiced for the day and set the value to 0€
           var dayTotal = document.getElementById("daytotal");
           dayTotal.innerHTML = "0€";
           //get the input values for invoiced and lastInvoiced
           var invoiced = document.getElementById("invoiced").value;
           var lastInvoiced = document.getElementById("lastinvoiced").value;
           //make sure the input values are number types. If not display 
           //message demanding to insert a valid value
           if (typeof invoiced !== Number)
               invoiced.innerHTML = "Insert a valid value!";
           if (typeof lastInvoiced !== Number)
               lastInvoiced.innerHTML = "Insert a valid value";
           //return the sum of the total by adding invoiced 
           //and lastInvoiced and adding the euro sign
           return invoiced + lastInvoiced + " €";
       }

   };
```

Comment: So, there are several text boxes in there, which one are you targeting? All?

Comment: In the first function I want ot get the input values from the first two text boxes and them display the result of their sum in the td with the id "daytotal"

Comment: And your fiddle doesn't have the function `calcTotalDay` that you have listed above in your code. Mistake?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I pasted the wrong link to my fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/mqu7A/

Comment: You still gave the same link... Probably you are in a hurry ;)

Comment: So sorry about the link :(
http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/mqu7A/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your fiddle doesn't have this `calcTotalDay` function, I will make assumptions which I believe are correct:

```
var A = {

   //calculate the total invoiced for the day
   calcTotalDay: function () {

       //get the total invoiced for the day and set the value to 0€
       var dayTotal = document.getElementById("daytotal");
       dayTotal.innerHTML = "0€";

       //get the input values for invoiced and lastInvoiced ""parsed as integers""
       var invoiced = parseInt(document.getElementById("invoiced").value, 10);
       var lastInvoiced = parseInt(document.getElementById("lastinvoiced").value, 10);

       //make sure the input values are number types. If not display 
       //message demanding to insert a valid value
       var type1 = typeof invoiced;
       var type2 = typeof lastInvoiced;
       if (type1 !== 'number')
           invoiced.innerHTML = "Insert a valid value!";
       if (type2 !== 'number')
           lastInvoiced.innerHTML = "Insert a valid value";

       //return the sum of the total by adding invoiced  
       //and lastInvoiced and adding the euro sign ""only when both are numbers""
       if(type1 === 'number' && type2 === 'number')
           return invoiced + lastInvoiced + " €";
       else 
           return "invalid";
   }

};
```

Comment: You assumed correctly. Thank you!
I see where I was missing the parseInt and the radix.
However, don't I need an event handler? Still nothing happens when I insert a value into the two text boxes.

Comment: @MMendes Yes you need! I thought you had one :D P.S. You can accept this answer if it helped. Thank you!

Comment: your answer was vey helpful. Thanks ;)